# Python, how can I add +1 to the z in b[z]?

Tags: python

What I want is to add +1 to the range so it prints different input(b). Am I doing it wrong or what is the problem?

The output should make a frame of + around the inputed words, but instead of that it does this:

```
Number of words: 5
Word: a
Word: aa
Word: aaa
Word: aaaa
Word: aaaaa
+++++++++
+ a +
+ a +
+ a +
+ a +
+ a +
+++++++++
```

```
a=int(input("Number of words: "))
list=[]
z=0

for x in range(a):
    b=input("Word: ")
    list.append(b)
c=(max(list, key=len))
d=len(c)

print("++" + "+"*d + "++")

for y in range(a):
    print("+"+" "+b[z]+" "+"+")
    z+=1

print("++" + "+"*d + "++")
```

Comment: ``b`` is just the last input – ``aaaaa`` in your case. The description suggests you wanted to use ``list[z]`` instead of ``b[z]``.

Comment: Note that using proper variable names can get you a long way. ``a``, ``z``, ``b``, ``c``, ``d`` , ``y`` are nondescript and of same length, so easy to accidentally mix. ``list`` is a confusing name, since it shadows the builtin ``list`` type and doesn't say what it represents. Just using ``words`` instead of ``list`` and removing ``b`` by directly doing ``words.append(input("Word: "))`` should avoid the error or at least make it obvious.

Answer (score 1):

'list' is the array of words, not 'b'. I believe this does what you are trying to do:

```
a=int(input("Number of words: "))
list=[]
z=0

for x in range(a):
    b=input("Word: ")
    list.append(b)
c=(max(list, key=len))
d=len(c)

print("++" + "+"*d + "++")

for word in list:
    print("+"+" "+ word +" "+"+")

print("++" + "+"*d + "++")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=int(input("Number of words: "))
list=[]
z=0

for x in range(a):
    b=input("Word: ")
    list.append(b)
c=(max(list, key=len))
d=len(c)

print("++" + "+"*d + "++")

for y in range(a):
  d2 = d-len(list[z])
  print("+"+" "+list[z]+" "*d2+" +")
  z+=1

print("++" + "+"*d + "++")
```